# angular.injector(..).invoke in the console not returning a singleton

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, singleton

The script:

```
app = angular.module('app', [])

app.factory 'MyFactory', ->
  val: 'Clark Kent'

app.controller 'MainCtrl', ($scope, MyFactory) ->
  MyFactory.val = 'Waldo'
  $scope.myFactory = MyFactory
```

Put this in the console:

```
angular.injector(['ng','app']).invoke(function(MyFactory) { console.log(MyFactory); })
```

... and instead of `Waldo`, you get `Clark Kent` !!

**Why doesn't it return the same object?**

Check out [the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0RqihLsnHPI5PBJGduK2?p=preview)

Comment: Are you sure that `MainCtrl` has actually been executed? Because what you've written right there doesn't look like it will invoke `MainCtrl`, which means everything is behaving as it should.

Comment: Yes, MainCtrl is invoked, that's why in the plunkr it says `Hello Waldo` in the output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Services in Angular are singletons in the sense that they are only created once per injector.

`angular.injector` however creates a new injector function.

To get the current app injector: `angular.element(domElement).injector()`

For your example:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('html')).injector().invoke(function(MyFactory) { console.log(MyFactory); })
```

Comment: Please take a look at the angular doc where it says "The following always holds true". Doesn't this contradict your statement that "angular.injector creates a new injector"? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector

Comment: No. In the example angular.injector is used to create a new injector. Then that injector is used to retrieve itself, which it is able to.