# angular.injector.invoke makes my controller undefined

Tags: angularjs, singleton-type

While learning angular, read [a blog](https://thinkster.io/egghead/injectors) which elaborate that

we can access factory/service outside of controller using [angular.injector()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)  , But when I try this, it gives my *main controller is undefined* error and everything stops working.

see the [**`working plunker`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/X1NAJPepma9bCGkxY4W1?p=preview)  with commented culprit code block.Below is main code of lines using `angular.injector(["app"]).invoke`

```
var app = angular.module('AlphaModule', []);
// service added 
app.service('tea', function(){
    return {
        teaType: function(teaType) {
            console.log('Service => Morning tea must be ' + teaType);
        },
        sayHello: function(msg) {
            console.log('Service  => Hello ' + msg);
        }
    };
});

// ERROR in console when uncomment this code block
angular.injector(["app"]).invoke(function(tea){
    tea.sayHello('Yellow');
});

// main controller definition
var AlphaController = function($injector, tea) {
    var vm  = this;
    vm.timeNow = new Date().getTime();
    ....
};

app.controller('AlphaController', AlphaController );
```

Please highlight what am I missing/ wrong doing  here?

**My Guess:**

I also read that **$injector are singleton** . What exactly this means? can we use `$injector` only once! or may be this is the issue as i have used $injector in `.controller` also

Comment: While the accepted answer is correct, it does not do what you think it does. `angular.injector` creates a new injector, it will not retrieve the injector associated with the app you have already created. Services are singletons in the sense that they are created only once per injector. So the `tea` service in your `invoke`will not be the same as the `tea` service in your app.

Comment: will you elaborate " the tea service in your invoke will not be the same as the tea service in your app" by example. I really keen to learn.

Comment: When your application is bootstrapped an injector will be created and associated when your app. Services used in your app will only be created once (per injector, which means per app). `angular.injector` creates a new injector and will create all services needed once again. So the service instance will not be the same, which will cause problem if your service keeps any state.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22969603/2887841

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your module name mentioned is wrong. module name is actualy `AlphaModule` not `app`.

```js
angular.injector(["AlphaModule"]).invoke(function(tea){
    tea.sayHello('Yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not understand why error are not so clear:(

Comment: will you please take a look on my previous question ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850557/with-no-named-function-for-get-in-provider-is-working-fine

Comment: This can be misleading. See my comment on the question.